# jquery mobile data-theme not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a simple log in page and I'm trying to apply theme "b" to it, but it doesn't work. The page looks dark and not the way theme b should look like.
Any idea?

Thanks.

My header

```
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/favicon.ico">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/themes/default/jquery.mobile-1.4.0.min.css">        
    <!--<link href="css/ios_inspired/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />-->
    <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jqm-demos.css">-->
    <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.0/jquery.js"></script>        
    <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.0/jquery.mobile-1.4.0.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>


    <div data-role="page" id="Page_Login"  data-quicklinks="true" data-theme="b" >

        <div data-role="header" >
            <h1>My header</h1>                
        </div>

        <div role="main" class="ui-content jqm-content jqm-fullwidth" data-theme="b" >

            <h1 style=" text-align:center;">Connect</h1>                  

            <form dir="rtl">

                <!--<div data-role="fieldcontain" >-->
                 <label for="txtEmail">email:</label>
                 <input type="email" name="txtEmail" id="txtEmail" value="" />
                <!--</div> -->      

                <!--<div data-role="fieldcontain" >-->
                 <label for="txtPassword">password:</label>
                 <input type="password" name="txtPassword" id="txtPassword" value="" />
                <!--</div> --> 

                <a  href="" data-transition="flip" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all" onclick="MemberLogIn()">connect</a>                         
            </form>

        </div><!-- /content -->

    </div><!-- /page -->            

</body>
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

> ### Update
>
> The classic theme should be upgraded to work properly with jQuery Mobile 1.4.x
>
> [Upgrade guide](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26991241/1771795)

---

Unlike old versions of jQuery Mobile, the latest version 1.4 has only two themes/swatches *a* and *b*. The latter is dark/black theme.

1. You can either create your own themes using [ThemeRoller](http://themeroller.jquerymobile.com/).
2. Use classic style sheet offered by jQuery Mobile, along with default style sheet.

   ```
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.0/jquery.mobile-1.4.0.min.css" />
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.0/theme-classic/theme-classic.css" />
   ```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/8xP3J/)**

Comment: I have used the classic style sheet like you said and my page now looks like a dream. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Itay.B You're welcome, I'm glad I've been of help :) just make sure to host it locally, you never know when jQM removes it ;)

Comment: This wasn't exactly what I was looking for, but this answer and this conversation really helped me to eventually work through it. Thanks guys! Shalom!