# I want to make A JQuery 1.4.0 Site look like JQuery 1.32

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have a mobile app for which I need a fix in JQuery Mobile 1.4.0 (specifically the checkbox issue).

However, when I upgrade, it completely changes the style (stylesheets, colors, etc).

Is there a way that I can get the same look using JQuery Mobile 1.4.0?

Comment: Is the jquery version the only thing that you are changing?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery mobile data-theme not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21547036/jquery-mobile-data-theme-not-working)

Comment: Omar - you've helped me out! How can I mark your answer as right?

Comment: @bluerain upvote the answer in the link ;)

Comment: That't exactly right "1.4 has only two themes" Dark and Light.