# How to duplicate data-theme="b" in Jquery Mobile 1.4?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm upgrading an existing site from jquery-mobile 1.0 to jquery-mobile 1.4.2.

The site had been using data-theme="b", and I'd like to maintain that styling. The problem? 1.4.2 provides only two themes, neither of which looks anything like the old theme "b".

What is the easiest way to restore the old look?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery mobile data-theme not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21547036/jquery-mobile-data-theme-not-working)

Comment: I know that the theming has changed.  The question, which wasn't addressed in the possible duplicate, is how to create a theme that matches the old style.

Comment: in the answer you'll find links to old themes that are compatible with 1.4.2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK.  I think I've found the trick.

1. Go to the [ThemeRoller for jQuery Mobile](http://themeroller.jquerymobile.com/%20themeroller) site.
2. From the jQuery Mobile Version dropdown, select version 1.0.1
3. Click on the "Import (or upgrade)" button
4. Click on "Import Default Theme"
5. In the "Upgrade to version:" dropdown, select 1.4.2
6. Click "Import"

That should give you a theme with the old styling loaded.

Comment: This worked very well, just to add that it also worked when I upgraded from 1.2.1 to 1.4.2.  Much easier than trying to manually recreate each element in the ThemeRoller.

Comment: I know this is a year old, but great answer, saved me lots of time.

Answer (score 1):

The easy way is to go to [Jquery mobile roller site](http://themeroller.jquerymobile.com/), ensure version 1.4.2 is selected at the top section of the page. You will be presented with swatches which will include theme b with default values (you can create new swatch b if not listed). You can then customize the look and feel of the b theme to look like what you want from the left panel; download the css from the top menu and overwrite all the necessary js and css file in your application.

Alternatively, if you are very sound in css, inspect the css files of JQuery mobile and carefully create/modify/overwrite the b section. The full css is well documented for understanding