# changing my jquery mobile theme changes my css styling

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-mobile

I have a collapsible set that I create on my website which looks similar to this:

```
<div data-role="collapsible-set" id="result" style="margin: auto; padding-top: 50px; padding-bottom: 20px;">
     <div>
         <h2>
        <span style="font-size: 16px; font-weight: bold; white-space: pre-wrap;" id="title' + num + '">abc</span><br>
        <span style="font-size: 14px; font-weight: normal;" id="author' + num + '"></span>
        <div style="font-weight: normal;">
            <span style="font-style:italic; font-size: 13px;" id="journal' + num + '"></span>
        </div>
        </h2>
        <div style="font-size: 14px;">
            more info
        </div>
     </div>       
</div>
```

However, after I apply a theme to each element I add to the collapsible set, my styling is changed and I can't figure out why. Before I append a div inside my collapsible set I'm adding the following attribute:

```
div.setAttribute("data-theme", "c");
```

This is what my list item looks like before styling:

[image]

And here is what it looks like after I add a theme:

[image]

as you can see, the spacing between each line is now pretty large. I've tried to change the css using padding but that didn't change anything. Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Here is a before and after fiddle:

[Before](http://jsfiddle.net/k9ocb8sg/4/)

[After](http://jsfiddle.net/5nfgbosg/)

Comment: Provide it in a fiddle. it ll be easy to chk for us

Comment: I have added two fiddle's. thanks

Comment: try changing the `line-height` value of `.ui-btn` from `1.3` to `0.5`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to *upgrade* `theme-classic.css` using [jQuery Mobile ThemeRoller](http://themeroller.jquerymobile.com/).

1. Go to [download page](http://jquerymobile.com/download/) and scroll down to "*Legacy versions*"
2. Under version 1.3.2 - CSS open [Uncompressed with Default theme: jquery.mobile-1.3.2.css](http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.css), copy its' content.
3. Go to [jQuery Mobile ThemeRoller](http://themeroller.jquerymobile.com/), from top toolbar, click "*Import or upgrade*". A new window will open
4. On that window, paste 1.3.2 CSS styles. From selectmenu, select "*Upgrade to version 1.4.5*" and then click "*Import*" button
5. Review copied themes, do changes if you want. Once done, click "*Download*" from top toolbar, give your theme a custom name and download upgraded classic themes.
6. Place new theme and other dependencies in the following order

   ```
   <head>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/themes/my-custom-theme.css" />
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/themes/jquery.mobile.icons.min.css" />
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.structure-1.4.5.min.css" /> 
     <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script> 
     <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
   </head>
   ```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/e3tdpxLn/)**

Comment: This worked perfectly to change the styles accordingly. Very detailed instructions too. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Applying a theme changes the look and feel of HTML elements as here

> div.setAttribute("data-theme", "c");

data-theme might be having a CSS class of its own which is effecting your webpage design

Are you using any CSS framework like BootStrap?
Try adding this theme element to the exact div where you wish a design change

Comment: I'm not using any css framework. I've added links to fiddle examples to further explain. thanks

Comment: you said that each theme might have it's own css class which  is causing a problem. Is there a way I can override that?

Comment: I couldn't see the blue heading version of your div which happens after adding the theme on your fiddle

Comment: check this link ... http://www.adobe.com/devnet/dreamweaver/articles/theme-control-jquery-mobile.html here you can learn how to create your own data-theme swatches