# jQuery Mobile- data-theme="d" is not working

Tags: jquery-mobile

I want to use data-theme d in my select. How ever jQuery Mobile ignores the `data-theme="d"`and display it as theme a.

```
<div id="mutualFriends">

    <select class="sortBy" name="sortBy" data-url="${url}" data-theme="d">
        <option value="">Sort By</option>
        <option value="new" selected="selected">Newest</option>
        <option value="old">Oldest</option>
        <option value="firstName_asc">First Name a-z</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Which version of jQuery Mobile are you using? Recent ones only have the `a` and `b` themes out of the box.

Comment: @ Frédéric Hamidi- 1.4.3

Comment: Well then, if you did not add a `d` swatch to the theme file, it won't be there.

Comment: You can try importing your current theme file in [ThemeRoller](http://themeroller.jquerymobile.com/) and build from there.

Comment: if you want to use old theme/swatch, check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/26991241/1771795