# Default CSS colours being shown on JQuery Mobile website

Tags: jquery, css, html, jquery-mobile

I have built [a mobile app](http://titan.dcs.bbk.ac.uk/~bbaker02/madfma/index.html)
and on the following page the default CSS for links is being shown when a transition between pages takes place.

[Link to mobile app webpage](http://titan.dcs.bbk.ac.uk/~bbaker02/madfma/location-01-images-room.html).

Answer (score 0):

Open your browsers inspector, find the a element and then write your own css for the document in a new files, preferably.

Comment: It doesn't apply the CSS. Take a look at the transition when the page changes ( http://titan.dcs.bbk.ac.uk/~bbaker02/madfma/location-01-images-room.html). Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: You want to style the nav's a hrefs, correct? Then you can target it with this: .ui-page-theme-a .ui-btn:hover, html .ui-bar-a .ui-btn:hover, html .ui-body-a .ui-btn:hover, html body .ui-group-theme-a .ui-btn:hover, html head + body .ui-btn.ui-btn-a:hover

Comment: A theme has been applied but during the transition between pages (http://titan.dcs.bbk.ac.uk/~bbaker02/madfma/location-01-images-room.html) the CSS appears to visually default to CSS defaults for links.

Comment: You might want to read this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21547036/jquery-mobile-data-theme-not-working

Comment: I read the post and comments but it hasn't helped. Have you been able to replicate the problem by viewing the web pages that I provided?